# downloaded pdf file not opening

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am saving a pdf file in the database by the following code

```
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string filetype = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        int filesize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;


        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] content = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);



        Objects.Insert_FilesToDatabase(filename, filetype, content,filesize);
```

and then, Iam trying to save the file from the database by clicking the link thru the following code.

```
     void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filetype = Objects.GetFileType(Convert.ToInt32(txtslno.Text.Trim()));
        string filename=Objects.GetFileName(Convert.ToInt32(txtslno.Text.Trim()));
        int filesize = Objects.GetFileLength(Convert.ToInt32(txtslno.Text.Trim()));
        byte[] bytfile = new byte[filesize+1000];

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",attachment;filename="+filename+".pdf");
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.Charset = "";

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytfile);

        Response.End();

    }
```

Thru this code, I am able to download the pdf file but I am unable to open the pdf file. The error is the file is not decoded properly. Can you help me as to where am I going wrong?

Comment: **Post the full error message**

Comment: Adobe reader could not open  because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged(for example,it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)

Comment: Why are you adding 1000 here `byte[] bytfile = new byte[filesize+1000];` ?

Comment: What kind of database? Sql Server? Oracle? What data type are you using to store the PDF within the database? You might also note that you only retrieve metadata regarding the PDF from the database. You allocate a `byte[]` that can hold the contents, but never populate it with content from the database.

Comment: I doubted if the file creation requires some additional bytes of memory for adding headers. so i gave some 1000 bytes extra. But I removed it and ran the program..I am getting the same error..it makes not difference..

Comment: @ Nicholas..I am using sqlserver 2008. i stored the data as varbinary(max)

Comment: @codewarrior As bUKaneer stated, it is obvious that Acrobat Reader can't read junk data - `byte[] bytfile = new byte[filesize+1000];` You should return a valid pdf file to browser.

Comment: I can't tell from just the code you passed how you are writing and retrieving the bytes from the db.  However you can look at the dbfile project on Codeplex that does what you are trying to do to see working implementation.  The majority of the code that writes the bytes out is here: http://dbfile.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70298#79334 and the code that works with sql server is here: http://dbfile.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70298#79303  there are other classes that also show using sprocs or filestreams.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem thru the following code..

```
        byte[] bytfile = Objects.GetFile(Convert.ToInt32(txtslno.Text.Trim()));
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+filename);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytfile.Length.ToString());
        Response.OutputStream.Write(bytfile, 0, bytfile.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

I am just not writing the binary content to the output pdf stream in my previous code..
Thank you for your support

Comment: If this is a solution for OP, please mark this as `Accepted Answer` so that it'll help others too.

Comment: It IS the solution and an excellent one!!! THANK YOU @codewarrior!